# Bug in GA4 Data API: DimensionFilter Fails with Full-Width Characters in Event Names

Tags: google-analytics-api

I have encountered a bug within the Google Analytics Data API (GA4) related to event filtering using the `DimensionFilter`.

Specifically, when applying a filter to events that include the full-width characters "（" and ”　" in their names, the returned data set is unexpectedly empty.

In contrast, filtering by events with their equivalent half-width characters "(" and " " yields the correct data.

For this issue, I utilized the `FilterExpression` as detailed in the API documentation: [FilterExpression Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/FilterExpression?hl=ja).

Additionally, I attempted to replicate the output using the GA4 API's Query Explorer, which resulted in the same issue ([image_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbwZ0.jpg)).

It's worth noting that the presence of data for these events is confirmed via the Google Analytics 4 admin interface ([image_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lD9Xk.png)).

Reproduction

- Metrics: eventCount
- Dimensions: deviceCategory, eventName
- DimensionFilter: eventName → "（" or "　"

Comment: you can bug report it [issue fourmn](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187400)  or try some of the [help forumns](https://developers.google.com/analytics/help#ask_questions)  there is even a link to a support request form.